# VPS + Vue.js Returning 404 on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, nginx, http-status-code-404, refresh, nginx-config

I created and deployed the vue js app on my VPS (Virtual Private Server), Ubuntu 22. For running this I use nginx (in the default file of the nginx changed destination from inde.html to my build) and everything goes fine until I refresh and then I get error 404.

I checked some posts, and I need to add some configuration, but that configuration is for Vercel I don't know what and where I need to set it when I use VPS.

Comment: being an SPA your web server needs to redirect any page/route that isnt your base URL to your base URL since all the routing is done client-side